# how assert result get count number only

Tags: groovy, assert, assertion

i want to assert the count return from sql query is correct but hitting error when using assert.
which assert i can use to just check the count number? or perhaps printIn only count number?

**codes**

```html
//SQL statement
String dbQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item.items WHERE drugid LIKE '%KP%'"


//Connect to SQL Server, global variable is stored at profile
List results = CustomKeywords.'DB.getSQLResults'(GlobalVariable.dbConnString , GlobalVariable.dbUsername , GlobalVariable.dbPassword ,GlobalVariable.dbDriver ,dbQuery )


//ensure total count
println results
assert results == "[:101]"
```

**result:**

```html
println(results)
[[:101]]
assert results == "[:101]"
Test Cases/Database Test FAILED.
Reason:
Assertion failed: 

assert results == "[:101]"
       |       |
       |       false
       [[:101]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got a list of maps there.

```
assert results == [['':101]]
assert results[0].get('') == 101
```

Should both return true.

Also if you change your SQL to

```
String dbQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM item.items WHERE drugid LIKE '%KP%'"
```

You should get

```
assert results == [[count:101]]
assert results[0].count == 101
```